# ERROR on HDD/RAID

Tags: dmesg

Any one can tell me what this mean...  (obtained using dmesg -T)

```
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: irq_stat 0x40000001
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: cmd 35/00:00:00:ac:9a/00:04:00:00:00/e0 tag                                                                                                                                           0 dma 524288 out
         res 61/04:00:00:ac:9a/00:04:00:00:00/e0 Emask 0x1 (device error)
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: status: { DRDY DF ERR }
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: error: { ABRT }
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: failed to enable AA (error_mask=0x1)
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/133 (device error ignore                                                                                                                                          d)
[vie oct 24 20:06:01 2014] ata3: EH complete
```

Answer (score 0):

looks similar to problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/319781/momentary-and-frequent-system-freeze-in-linux-mint

in short here are some possible causes:

- Inteferences on the SATA BUS. Might be solved by adjusting spread spectrum settings in the BIOS
- a hardware (disk) fault. consider the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sdX`
- a low-level device lock. consult `hdparm -I /dev/sdX`